# How dangerous is this: number of contracts contain a function like "approveandcall" which lets anyone call any contract (some thoughts?)

Tags: contract-development, security, delegatecall

The most common implementation is as follows:

```
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)  public returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        _spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        ApproveAndCall(_spender, _value, _extraData );
        return true;
    }
}
```

From what I can see it's obligatory that the receiving contract has "Receiveapproval" function, meaning a hacker can't really call anything...on another thought:

If a receiving contract has receiveapproval function with delegatecall inside and the delegatecall calls back the sender, it will achieve a little but still something? Why? Because while delegatecall doesn't change storage of receiver it preserves the message sender, so:

1. Contract A calls B via approveandcall
2. B has a.delegatecall to any function of A
3. A will receive the call from B looking as if it's from A but it will never change any storage on A.

Basically this can only be problem if A contains a very perverted function something like:

```
function allow_withdrawals_for_anyone() public 
{
require(msg.sender = address(this));
// you see the point
}
```

Or this will work too:
function allowwithdrawals() internal
{

// internal modifier should pass in this case 
}

This is just my understanding that while delegatecall doesn't change variables it at least registers a msg.sender which in this case is A, again I may be wrong but I see no other way of A knowing who the msg.sender is unless a function gets fully executed with a call.

If my reasoning is correct then I'd be happy to see cases of functions where this can be dangerous really.